# How to execute a unique shuffle using two for loops

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, shuffle

I'm trying to write a function called func1 that can shuffle a given deck of cards (an array) uniquely, given two other decks, the starting deck and the resulting deck. For example, a deck of cards [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] is shuffled and produces another deck of cards [4, 5, 2, 1, 3]. I want to complete this same shuffle (putting the card in slot 0 into slot 3, the card in slot 1 into slot 2, etc), but this time on another deck of cards [2, 3, 1, 5, 4]. It should print out [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] if I wrote the code correctly. Although it runs the program, it only prints the first "card" correctly, and the rest are really big numbers. What did I do wrong? Am I using the correct approach, or should I rethink my design?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int * func1(int *deck) // A unique shuffle given two decks, a starting and ending deck (in this case, "start" and "shuff1")
{
    int start[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 }; // Starting deck
    int shuff1[5] = { 4,5,2,1,3 }; // Resulting deck after shuffle. This is the specific type of shuffle that we are copying
    int finish[5] = {}; // The deck that we are returning

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // Looks at a specific spot (i) in the start deck...
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) // Looks through all the spots (j) in the shuff1 deck...
        {

            if (start[i] == shuff1[j]) // And if the cards themselves are identical, then it takes the ith card
            {                          // in the given deck and puts it in the jth spot in the finish deck
                int temp = deck[i];
                finish[j] = temp;
                j = 5;
            }

        }
    }

    return finish;

}

int main()
{
    int test[5] = { 2,3,1,5,4 }; // Given deck
    int* shuff2 = func1(test); // Calls a specifc shuffle and sets it equal to a deck called shuff2

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << shuff2[i] << endl; // Prints shuff2

    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tip: Question all uses of pointers in C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

Your `func1` returns a pointer to `finish`, which is a variable local to the function. When control passes out of the function, that variable passes out of scope-- you could say it *expires.* So the pointer points to a spot in the wilderness of invalid memory, and dereferencing the pointer (e.g. by `shuff2[i]`) causes *undefined behavior,* which means strange numbers if you're lucky.

One solution is to have `func1` construct `finish` on the heap. Another is to have the function accept a pointer to the array which it should fill with shuffled values; the calling code (e.g. `main`) would be responsible for providing a pointer to a valid array.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you are returning a pointer to a variable allocated on the stack, which you can't do.  Pass a pointer to "finish" as a second argument instead.

I'm not sure if I am following the way you described the proposed algorithm very well, but I think you would want to create an array of offsets, like this:

```
void func1(int *deck, int *finish) {
    int offsets[5] = {3, 1, 2, -3, -3};
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        finish[i + offsets[i]] = deck[i];
    }
}
```

or put the actual destination indexes into the array:

```
void func1(int *deck, int *finish) {
    int desti[5] = {3, 2, 4, 0, 1};
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        finish[desti[i]] = deck[i];
    }
}
```

Though you did specifically say "using two for loops" so maybe I'm misunderstanding the way you described the algorithm.